# PHP cURL different result with cuRL in bash command line

Tags: php, bash, curl

I try to get html result from a site using cURL in PHP, and I got 301 moved permanently, But when I use command line, it working and returning html string reuslt.

This is my Code PHP (result not success)

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://detail.1688.com/offer/535394058500.html?spm=b26110380.sw1688.mof001.302.6YIDM0&v=1",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "a=b",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "postman-token: b60107e9-4350-e93f-d6cf-d626505687b8"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response; // return 301 moved permanent
    }
```

And this is in CMD (result success)

```
curl -X GET   'https://detail.1688.com/offer/535394058500.html?spm=b26110380.sw1688.mof001.302.6YIDM0'   -H 'cache-control: no-cache'   -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'   -H 'postman-token: 2b11da6f-dcde-d527-289c-bfbf8a85d30c'
```

Comment: You need to tell curl to follow redirects: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it's working for redirect, but to my own homepage not the target site

Comment: What do you mean? Your curl request gets a 301 (which is a redirect) and your request doesn't follow it, since you're not receiving the HTML from the correct page. Setting that param will tell curl to continue to the location header it gets on the 301 response. Have you tried it?

Comment: as I said, the result between CMD cURL and php cURL is different, in cmd its working fine, but in php its showing redirect (it seems blocked) @MagnusEriksson

Comment: ...and my comment referred to your PHP that doesn't follow redirects by default. Please try adding the above option to curl in your PHP-script and try.

Comment: I have tried to add code that you mentioned, but it is redirecting to my own website (localhost). I mean why cmd cURL have different result with php cURL whereas its have a same code

Comment: Hm. Looking at the response header, it shows this as a redirect url: `http://127.0.0.1/?spm=b26110380.sw1688.mof001.302.6YIDM0&v=1` which is localhost. Why that happens when using curl through PHP is beyond me, though. I know that some curl versions had some issues with relative redirect URL's in the past, but that should have been fixed.